# TypeError at /students/exam/1/ int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I'm trying to submit this form through this model and views, but I am getting the TypeError which is shown in the screenshot. Though I want to also submit it to the database. I have taking all my value just to drop it into database.

[image]

I'd be very happy if you'd assist to solve the `save()` method as well.

student.py:

```python
@login_required
@student_required
def take_exam(request, pk):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=pk)
    student = request.user.student
    question = course.questions.filter()  
    #correct_answers = student.course_answers.filter(answer__question__quiz=course, answer__is_correct=True).count()
    total_questions = course.questions.count()
    choice = Answer.objects.filter()
    marks_obtainable = Details.objects.get(course_id=course)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        question_pk = request.POST.getlist('question_pk')
        question_obj = Question.objects.filter(id=int(question_pk))

        choice_pk = [request.POST['choice_pk{}'.format(q)] for q in question_obj]

        #print(marks_obtainable.marks_obtained)
        zipped = zip(question_obj, choice_pk)

        for x, y in zipped:
            correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=x,  is_correct=True).values("id").first()['id']

            print(x, y, correct_answers)
            if int(y) == int(correct_answers):
                #z = TakenQuiz(student=student, course=course, \
                    #question=x, selected_choice=y,  marks_obtained=marks_obtainable, is_correct=True)
                print("correct")
            else:
                print("Not Correct")

    return render(request, 'classroom/students/take_exam_form.html', {
        'course': course,
        'question': question,
        'course': course,
        'total_questions': total_questions,
        'choice': choice,
        'marks_obtainable': marks_obtainable

    })
```

models.py:

```python
class Question(models.Model):

    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField('Question', max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    text = models.CharField('Answer', max_length=255)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

take_exam_form.html:

```html
<h2 class="mb-3">{{ course.name }}</h2>
Course id <h2 class="mb-3">{{ course.id }}</h2>
Student id <h2 class="mb-3">{{ request.user.id }}</h2>
Total Question:  <h2 class="mb-3">{{ total_questions }}</h2>
Mark Obtainable <h2 class="mb-3">{{ marks_obtainable.maximum_marks }}</h2>

<form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for questions in question %}
        <input type="hidden" name="question_pk" value="{{ questions.pk }}">
        <h3 class="text-info">{{ questions.text|safe }}</h3>
    {% for choices in questions.answers.all %}

        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="choice_pk{{ questions.pk }}" id="choices-{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choices.pk }}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="choices-{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ choices.text|safe }}
        </label>

      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Now →</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand you..

Comment: There isn't enough information in the photo of the error you linked to. First, click on the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" (next to Traceback). Then copy and paste the full traceback in your question above. See [this page](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for an explanation of why images of errors/code isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the only int() call is in

```
int(y)
```

Try this `print(type(y))`. Maybe y is a list object. That's why the error said:

> The arg must be string or ... not a list